# Bootstrap CSS not working from local source

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Wordpress theme and I have downloaded the [Compiled CSS and JS files from getbootstrap official website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/#compiled-css-and-js).

I have moved all the files to my Theme directory, more specifically to /bootstrap/css and bootstrap/js accordingly.

When I call the file in my header.php, nothing happens. But if I use Bootstrap CDN the test website works. The solution might be obvious, but I'm simply not seeing it.

**in header.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <link href=”bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css” rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” />  
        <script type=”text/javascript” src=”bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js”></script>
```

Edit: Yes, the files bootstrap.min.css is located in bootstrap/css folder.

Comment: are the files 404ing? Look at the network panel

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in your code, `”`. Use `'` or `"`

Comment: You need to use `href="<?= get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/bootstrap..."` (the header.php file might be hosted in your theme folder, but it will be included in the main `index.php`, which is in the top folder)

Comment: Yes, actually bootstrap.min.js does give me 404, the path it is looking for is wordpress/js/bootstrap.min.js while it should be wordpress/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js.

In addition, it is not finding my style.css which is weird, since it is located in the root theme folder. 

I will try changing the quotes now.

Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: changing quotes doesen't help.

Comment: Is your theme activated? Did you refresh the page? Did you see my comment?

Comment: Thank you Chris, that worked. Edit. Can you post this as an anwser, so we can mark this post as Solved. It might also help someone in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not include hardcoded styles, try enqueueing in the `functions.php`file as the documentation states:
[wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Second, the reason why the loading works with the CDN is because it's finding the source directly from the repository. This tells us that the path of your style is not right. Be sure that the theme structure be like this:

```
ThemeName/bootstrap/css/
```

Last as @Chris G said, you should use the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` function to get the file's relative path.